# How to initiate a devise logout with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, devise, sweetalert2

I am wanting to use Sweetalert2 to initiate a devise logout / sign out but the code below is generating an invalid CSRF token error in rails.

The below code initiates a DELETE HTTP request to the devise sign out URL but that's when when the CSRF error occurs and doesn't sign out. Note the ERB tag for destroy_user_session_path. It produces the same error if I hard code the link to the logout page.

Any help on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated.

```js
function logoutSwal() {
    Swal.fire({
    title: 'Ready to Leave?',
    text: "Select 'Logout' below if you are ready to end your current session.",
    type: 'question',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    confirmButtonText: 'Logout'
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {
            fetch('<%= destroy_user_session_path %>', {
                method: 'DELETE'
            }
        }
    })
}
```

**UPDATE**

The below function now partially works, it correctly logs out (deletes the session) but doesn't redirect to the login page. If I refresh the page (CTRL-R) I am taken to the login page. I suspect the issue is now something to do with the devise controller and responding to AJAX / JSON?

Do I have to update the controller to respond (i.e. redirect) to this request?

*Function:*

```js
window.ajaxLogout = function(logoutUrl) {
    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Ready to Leave?',
        text: "Select 'Logout' below if you are ready to end your current session.",
        type: 'question',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        confirmButtonText: 'Logout'
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {
            $.ajax({
                url: logoutUrl,
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content')
                },
                type: "DELETE"
            })
        }
    })
}
```

*Log entry when running the function:*

```
Started DELETE "/logout" for IPXXX at 2019-10-29 19:14:47 -0400

Processing by Users::SessionsController#destroy as */*
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Account Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "public"."accounts".* FROM "public"."accounts" WHERE "public"."accounts"."subdomain_name" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["subdomain_name", "demo"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"
   (0.3ms)  COMMIT
Completed 204 No Content in 19ms (ActiveRecord: 3.8ms)
```

Comment: read documentation for fetch ... *By default, fetch won't send or receive any cookies from the server* ... so I'm assuming it's a lack of cookie problem ... you'll want the appropriate `credentials` option in your `init` argument (the second one) - see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch#Parameters)

Comment: Thanks, that put me on the right path. I can now pass a valid CSRF token to the controller and delete the session but its not redirecting (as it normally would for an HTML response) to the login page with a success message. See update above.

Comment: `its not redirecting` what isn't? The current page? `$.ajax` loads data, doesn't change the current page

Comment: wow, so you abandoned `fetch` and went for `jQuery.ajax` instead? I take it you already use jQuery and didn't load jQuery just for this!

Comment: Yes jQuery was already loaded, was just trying ajax. Fetch and ajax both have the same issue with the redirect. More specifically the Devise Session Controller actions aren't running. See here for the controller actions (by actions i mean the flash notice and the `respond_to_on_destroy` method: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/14863ba4c92cd9781a961be0486f0ea7dfe84144/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb#L27

Answer (score 0):

In the end I just used the ajax success function to redirect to the login page.

```
window.ajaxLogout = function(logoutUrl, loginUrl) {
  Swal.fire({
    title: "Ready to Leave?",
    text: "Select 'Logout' below if you are ready to end your current session.",
    icon: "question",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: "#3085d6",
    confirmButtonText: "Logout"
  }).then(result => {
    if (result.value) {
      $.ajax({
        url: logoutUrl,
        type: "DELETE",
        success: function() {
          window.location.href = loginUrl;
        }
      });
    }
  });
};
```